# Generating a PDF with sequential order images FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf with some images using **PhP FPdf**. I need 4 (four) images per page and 2 (two) images per row. The [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/) seems to be pretty simple but I still don't get why it's not working. First time working with this library, so sorry if I made some newbe mistake. If anyone could suggest me a better way to do I will appreciate. Here's my code.

```
$imagesPerPage = 1;
$imagesPerRow = 0;

    if ($itens !== false) {
        //Add a page if there's at least a single image
        $pdf->AddPage();
        foreach ($itens as $item) {
            //if more than 4 images will generate another page
            if($imagesPerPage > 4){
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $imagesPerPage = 1;
            }

            //Set image in their cordinates into the pdf file
            $pdf->Image($item, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 0);
            $imagesPerRow ++;

            //Put side by side or if the row is complete put bellow
            if($imagesPerRow === 1){
                $pdf->Cell(80, 0, "", 0, 0);            
            }else{
                $pdf->Cell(80, 0, "", 0, 2);
                $imagesPerRow = 0;
            }
            $imagesPerPage ++;
        }
    }
```

**And heres the output I get...**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXUdy.jpg)

Comment: What precisely is not working? Are you getting an error or are the images not displaying the way you want them to?

Comment: @Tristan updated with a link to the pdf its generating

Comment: Looks like your images are simply to big. Try to use 4th and 5th param of $pdf->Image(string file , float x , float y [, float w] [, float h] [, string type] [, mixed link]) to set an explicit width/height.

Comment: @maxhb still not working I can see all the images now, but it's generating two pages, and the first row of the first page has more than two images. It seems more like this code is not doing what I'd like to **$pdf->Cell(100, 0, "", 0, 2);** to jump to the "next row"

Comment: You don't need cells. Just place the images side by side and after 2 images return to left border and increase y coordinate. Cells are used for displaying texts, not for aligning images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the new row you can use `$pdf->SetXY();` to reset the location of the next row.

```
$imagesPerPage = 1;
$imagesPerRow = 0;
if ($itens !== false) {
    //Add a page if there's at least a single image
    $pdf->AddPage();
    foreach ($itens as $item) {
        //if more than 4 images will generate another page
        if($imagesPerPage > 4){
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $imagesPerPage = 1;
        }
        //Set image in their cordinates into the pdf file
        $pdf->Image($item, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 0);
        $imagesPerRow ++;
        //Put side by side or if the row is complete put bellow
        if($imagesPerRow === 1){
            $pdf->Cell(80, 0, "", 0, 0);            
        }else{
            $pdf->SetXY(15, 0);
            $pdf->Cell(80, 0, "", 0, 2);
            $imagesPerRow = 0;
        }
        $imagesPerPage ++;
    }
}
```